# C# Webbrowser edit mode: press "enter " leads to new paragraph

Tags: c#, mshtml

I have a little WPF App that uses the webbrowser-control in combination with mshtml  as html editor. That works really well so far, but:
When I press the Key "Enter", then the webbrowser adds a new paragraph

into the mshtml document. I need a simple line-break  instead, because the line spacing is too big with Paragraphs. Does anybody have an idea how I can get that effect?

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbbHTMLeMail" PreviewKeyDown="WbbHTMLeMail_PreviewKeyDown"/>

wbbHTMLeMail.NavigateToString(CurrentEmail.Body);
doc = wbbHTMLeMail.Document as HTMLDocument;
doc.designMode = "ON";
wbbHTMLeMail.PreviewKeyDown += WbbHTMLeMail_PreviewKeyDown;
```

I tried to catch the PreviewKeyDown-event, but I don't know how to inject the line break into the mshtml document.
One try was to do something like this:

```
 private void WbbHTMLeMail_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                var sText = doc.selection.createRange();
                sText.execCommand("Paste", false, "</br>");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
}
```

But that didn't work, it only inserts the "/br>" as plain text.
Does anybody have an idea how to get only a simple line break when pressing the Enter-key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend this:

```
private void WbbHTMLeMail_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                var sText = doc.selection.createRange();
                sText.execCommand("Paste", false, Environment.NewLine);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. The browser/document isn't responding to this command at all